# Shuffle array in Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I want to shuffle the numbers in my `array` variable once, so I called my `Shuffle` method from `Start()`.

I then attempt access the shuffled array from update, but I am unable to do so. How can I access it? Is there any other way to shuffle my array once, then use it forever?

```
private System.Random _random = new System.Random();
float sec;
float timecount;
float starttime;
void Start () {
    starttime = Time.time;
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    Shuffle(array);
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Debug.Log(value);
    }
}

void Update () {
    //time
    timecount = Time.time - starttime;
    sec = (timecount % 60f);
    if (Mathf.Round(sec) == 3f) {
        //access shuffled array
        Debug.Log(array[3]);  <=====error here
    }
}

//for shuffle number from array
void Shuffle(int[] array){
    int p = array.Length;
    for (int n = p-1; n > 0 ; n--)
    {
        int r = _random.Next(1, n);
        int t = array[r];
        array[r] = array[n];
        array[n] = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your array is declared within your `Start()` function.  This means it can only be accessed from within the `Start()` function.  If you want to be able to access the array from both `Start()` and `Update()` you need to increase its scope by declaring it globally.  For example:

```
private System.Random _random = new System.Random();
float sec;
float timecount;
float starttime;

//declare array globally
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

void Start () 
{
  starttime = Time.time;
  Shuffle(array);
  foreach (int value in array)
  {
      Debug.Log(value);
  }
}

void Update () 
{
    //now you can access array here, because it is declared globally
}
```

Additionally, have a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) about scope in C#.

Comment: but if i declared it globally, if i call array [1], for example, the value shown is before shuffled, so it's still array[1]=2

Comment: are you calling array[1] before you have called your shuffle method?

Comment: i called shuffle method in start, because i want to shuffled it only once, then use the shuffled numbers in update function

Comment: so you are saying that after calling shuffle on your globally declared array in Start, they are not shuffled in update?

Comment: oh i checked and it works, sorry, i was careless, thanks :)

Comment: good to hear! be sure to accept the answer, so others know this is correct

Answer (score 2):

Move  `int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};` outside the Start function.

```
private System.Random _random = new System.Random();
float sec;
float timecount;
float starttime;

int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

void Start()
{
    starttime = Time.time;
    Shuffle(array);
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Debug.Log(value);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //time
    timecount = Time.time - starttime;
    sec = (timecount % 60f);
    if (Mathf.Round(sec) == 3f)
    {
        //access shuffled array
        Debug.Log(array[3]);
    }
}

//for shuffle number from array
void Shuffle(int[] array)
{
    int p = array.Length;
    for (int n = p - 1; n > 0; n--)
    {
        int r = _random.Next(0, n);
        int t = array[r];
        array[r] = array[n];
        array[n] = t;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: *Not related to your question*.

There is a bug in your Shuffle function. `array[0]` will always remain **1** and will never change. To fix this, replace `int r = _random.Next(1, n);` with `int r = _random.Next(0, n);`  in the Shuffle function.

Answer (score 0):

There is still a problem with this algorithm. Imagine an array with values 0, 1, 2
The possible shuffles should be:

```
0 1 2
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
```

and the probability of each case should be the same. To achieve this modify
`int r = _random.Next(0, n+1);` Because the max value of `Random.Next` is exclusive (see doc)