# how to force unity to avoid picking up a random object twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple enemy wave based survival game

the spawn system have an array of enemy AIs and Spawn Points, I want the spawned prefabs to be removed from the enemies array to avoid getting spawned again, is there a way to do so, here's my code:

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject[] enemies;


Pos= spawnPoints[Random.Range (0,spawnPoints.length)]);

AI = Instantiate (enemies[Random.Range (0, enemies.length)]) , Pos);
```

Comment: Shuffle the array then instantiate the first element, then the second element, etc.  [Shuffle array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702548/shuffle-array-in-unity)

Comment: the post u sent only change the order of variables in array, am looking  for a way to remove variables from it

Comment: @MoncifMo: So then a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457453/328193)?

Comment: thanks for pointing out :) I will try looking into it